# Robotium: Creating the test project for .apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, robotium

I am stuck in starting a new test project(using Robotium and Eclipse) for testing an application and I have only the .apk file.
I've followed all the tutorials from http://code.google.com/p/robotium/ but it seems I'm missing something.

1. I have the .apk file.
2. I've re-signed it as the tutorial says and the app was installed on the device.
3. Now I have to start a new test project in Eclipse. I have the TARGET_PACKAGE_ID and
   LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME.

What are the correct steps in order to link the application installed on the device to my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1):

I try the following procedures for a debug version apk. It works.

1. Create a android test project and "select test target" to any one (since you do not have the source code of the real target project)
2. Modify AndroidManifest.xml and change "android:targetPackage" to your real target package.
3. Write and run your blackbox test cases.